# Is there a way to create a "Verify Element Text is Not" keyword?

Tags: katalon-studio

I need to verify an element had been randomized from a fixed starting state. I already have a test step that verifies the fixed state is working that uses "Verify Element Text" is "inserttexthere".

So **I need a way to verify that the text is not "inserttexthere" after I click the randomizing button.**

**Is there anyway to do this that wouldn't require too much programming knowledge?** (I use katalon studio because I have limited tech knowledge)

**or is there an if else statement I can use that would pass the step only if the text is different?**

---

**Background and other methods I do know of or tried:**

I can create another verify text command and just accept it as an intended to fail step. However that's harder to be aware of, especially if the text doesnt change because the test step will pass and I have to remember thats bad.

The other commands that are available only cover if the element no longer has text or if the element is no longer visible/clickable. There is nothing that lets me verify an attribute as "!=" or "NOT"

Answer (score 0):

This is how you need to create a custom keyword in Katalon: [Click](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/introduction-to-custom-keywords.html#create-a-package)

Code:

```
    class help_keyword_elemtnotPresent {

        @Keyword
        def isElemetNotPresent() {

        WebUI.verifyElementNotPresent(findTestObject(‘someobject’, timeout, FailureHandling.OPTIONAL)

        }
```

for  : [if/else](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/mark-tests-status-for-a-custom-keyword.html)

[More example](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/sample-custom-keywords.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short beginners' **practical** tutorial:

1. Create a keyword in Keywords (1) (right-click, new keyword).

[image]

2. Create a package (2) (right-click, new package) called `examplePackage`.
3. Create a new class called `ExampleClass` inside that package:

```
public class ExampleClass {

    @Keyword
    public static verifyElementTextIsNot(String text1, String text2){
        assert text1 != text2
    }

}
```

Example test case showing how you can call the above keyword (Keyword is Katalon's name for method):

```
import static com.kms.katalon.core.checkpoint.CheckpointFactory.findCheckpoint
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testcase.TestCaseFactory.findTestCase
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.TestDataFactory.findTestData
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ObjectRepository.findTestObject
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ObjectRepository.findWindowsObject
import com.kms.katalon.core.checkpoint.Checkpoint as Checkpoint
import com.kms.katalon.core.cucumber.keyword.CucumberBuiltinKeywords as CucumberKW
import com.kms.katalon.core.mobile.keyword.MobileBuiltInKeywords as Mobile
import com.kms.katalon.core.model.FailureHandling as FailureHandling
import com.kms.katalon.core.testcase.TestCase as TestCase
import com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.TestData as TestData
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.TestObject as TestObject
import com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.keyword.WSBuiltInKeywords as WS
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords as WebUI
import com.kms.katalon.core.windows.keyword.WindowsBuiltinKeywords as Windows
import internal.GlobalVariable as GlobalVariable
import examplePackage.ExampleClass

String someText = "It is a rainy day"
String someOtherText = "It is a sunny day"


ExampleClass.verifyElementTextIsNot(someText, someOtherText)
```